# Split single comma delimited .txt file into multiple files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one comma delimited .txt file, which looks like:

```
1, Apple    
2, Banana
3, Carrot
```

I want to convert into two files:

[File 1]

```
1
2
3
```

[File 2]

```
Apple
Banana
Carrot
```

Comment: Is this a one-off, where loading the file into a spreadsheet program like Excel or LibreOffice Calc would be OK, or a repeating task?

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT}(http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "^(.*),\s*(.*?)\s*$" "$txt=$1;stdout.WriteLine($2)" /jq /f input.txt /o out1.txt > out2.txt`

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

In a `.bat` (batch) file you can split the file into two files with:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=, " %%a in (count.txt) do (
    echo %%a  >> col1.txt
    echo %%b  >> col2.txt
)
```

Comment: Tested, works for me. Nice solution.